# Exception while try to get jmeter directory

Tags: csv, jmeter, data-driven-tests

I would like to start jmeter load test via console but it's Data Driven Load Test, so I need to read some information from csv files. I found a solution to include into User Parameters row to get the path to the place where the script was launched:

```
${__BeanShell(newFile(org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getInstance().getTestPlanFile().toString()).getParent())}
```

but I got an error in logs:

> 2013/06/11 15:23:54 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error
>   invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of:
>   ``newFile(org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getInstance().getTestPlanFile().toStrin
>   . . . '' : Command not found: newFile( java.lang.String )
>
> 2013/06/11 15:23:54 WARN  - jmeter.functions.BeanShell: Error running
>   BSH script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh
>   method: eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of:
>   ``newFile(org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getInstance().getTestPlanFile().toStrin
>   . . . '' : Command not found: newFile( java.lang.String )     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter.bshInvoke(BeanShellInterpreter.java:192)

What's wrong with this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you have:

- newFile

instead of:

- new File